# Apache FOP 2.2 migration error - ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.batik.i18n.Localizable

Tags: java, apache, xslt, apache-fop

After migration to Apache FOP 2.2 there appeared error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.batik.i18n.Localizable
```

The reason is that `fop 2.2` uses `batik-util-1.9`. And the package `i18n` presenting in `batik-util-1.8` is removed in the version `1.9` but is required.
To fix it is possible just to use `batik-util-1.8` (eg. specifying in pom.xml) or just to add package `i18n` to the version `1.9` jar and also class `org.apache.batik.util.XmlConstants`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be found here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BATIK-1185

Comment: Please be more substantive in your answer. Link only answers aren't really considered good answers.

Comment: good information thanks. So it is just enough to add maven dependencies to batik-i18n and batik-constants both version 1.9